# How do I quickly match the fields of two files that are sorted but one is a subset of the other

Tags: python, perl, shell, sorting, merge

I have two sorted files and want to merge them to make a third, but I need the output to be sorted. One column in the second file is a subset of the first and any place the second file doesn't match the first should be filled in with a NA.  The files are large (~20,000,000) records each so loading things into memory is tough and speed is an issue.

File 1 looks like this:

```
1 a
2 b
3 c
4 d
5 e
```

File 2 looks like this:

```
1 aa
2 bb
4 dd
5 ee
```

And the the output should be like this

```
1 a aa
2 b bb
3 c NA
4 d cc
5 e ee
```

Answer (score 6):

`join` is your friend here.

```
join -a 1 file1 file2
```

should do the trick.  The only difference to your example output is that the unpairable lines are printed directly from `file1`, i.e. without the `NA`.

**Edit**: Here is a version that also handles the `NA`s:

```
join -a 1 -e NA -o 1.1 1.2 2.2 file1 file2
```

Comment: +1, amazing how often the standard unix tools get the job done.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly:

- File #1 and file #2 will have the same lines
- However, some lines will be missing from file #2 that are in file #1.
- AND, most importantly, the lines will be sorted in each file.

That means if I get a line from file #2, and the keep reading through file #1, I'll find a matching line sooner or later. Therefore, we want to read a line from file #2, keep looking through file #1 until we find the matching line, and when we do find one, we want to print out both values.

I would imagine some sort of algorithm like this:

```
Read first line from file #2
While read line from file #1
    if line from file #2 > line from file #1
        write line from file #1 and "NA"
    else
        write line from file #1 and file #2
        Read another line from file #2
    fi
done
```

There should be some form of error checking (what if you find the line from file #1 to be greater than the line from file #2? That means line #1 is missing the line.) And, there should be some boundary checking (what if you run out of lines from file #2 before you finish file #1?)

This sounds like a school assignment, so I really don't want to give an actual answer. However, the algorithm is there. All you need to do is implement it in your favorite language.

If it isn't a school assignment, and you need more help, just post a comment on this answer, and I'll do what I can.

---

## To the DNA Biologist

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl

use warnings;
use strict;
use feature qw(say);

use constant {
    TEXT1 =>        "foo1.txt",
    TEXT2 =>        "foo2.txt",
};


open (FILE1, "<", TEXT1) or die qq(Can't open file ) . TEXT1 . qq(for reading\n);
open (FILE2, "<", TEXT2) or die qq(Can't open file ) . TEXT2 . qq(for reading\n);

my $line2 = <FILE2>;
chomp $line2;
my ($lineNum2, $value2) = split(/\s+/, $line2, 2);
while (my $line1 = <FILE1>) {
    chomp $line1;
    my ($lineNum1, $value1) = split(/\s+/, $line1, 2);
    if (not defined $line2) {
        say "$lineNum1 - $value1 - NA";
    }
    elsif  ($lineNum1 lt $lineNum2) {               #Use "<" if numeric match and not string match
        say "$lineNum1 - $value1 - NA";
    }
    elsif ($lineNum1 eq $lineNum2) {
        say "$lineNum1 - $value1 - $value2";
        $line2 = <FILE2>;
        if (defined $line2) {
            chomp $line2;
            ($lineNum2, $value2) = split(/\s+/, $line2, 2);
        }
    }
    else {
        die qq(Something went wrong: Line 1 = "$line1" Line 2 = "$line2"\n);
    }
}
```

It wasn't thoroughly tested, but it worked on some short sample files.

Comment: It isn't a school assignment.  I am a biologist trying to learn how to deal with large DNA sequence datasets.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it all in shell:

```
sort file.1 > file.1.sorted
sort file.2 > file.2.sorted
join -e NA file.1.sorted file.2.sorted > file.joined
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a Python solution:
    """merge two files based on matching first columns"""

```
def merge_files(file1, file2, merge_file):
    with (open(file1) as file1,
          open(file2) as file2,
          open(merge_file, 'w')) as merge:
        for line2 in file2:
            index2, value2 = line2.split(' ', 1)
            for line1 in file1:
                index1, value1 = line1.split(' ', 1)
                if index1 != index2:
                    merge.write(line1)
                    continue
                merge.write("%s %s %s" % (index1, value1[:-1], value2))
                break
        for line1 in file1:  # grab any remaining lines in file1
            merge.write(line1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    merge_files('test1.txt','test2.txt','test3.txt')
```